# SQLite in Java(ask user to input a String and out put all data in table)

Tags: java, sqlite

So I have a table that has the following names

Joseph
Steven
Cory
Lory

I am trying to ask user to search for specific Strings in the names in the database/table and print out the name they provided

For example if the user inputs ory then Cory and Lory will print out
This is what I currently have

```
public void part3() {
            try {
                this.query = dbConnect.createStatement();

                //String userinput = sc.nextLine();

                ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM studentTable WHERE first_name LIKE 'userinput'");

                while(rs.next()) {
                    String fname = rs.getString("first_name");
                    String lname = rs.getString("last_name");
                    //fname.contains(userinput);

                    System.out.println(fname + " ");

                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It does not print out Cory, Lory

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the query you want to execute ?

ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM studentTable WHERE first_name LIKE 'userinput'");

Should it not be this instead ? pay attention to the %

ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM studentTable WHERE first_name LIKE '%userinput%'");